# Does every android app adjusts its internal state based on the user touch, and re-renders the screen?

Tags: android, c, user-interface, operating-system, render

I'm involved in a one year university project which attempts to demonstrate that an Android app can be built entirely in C.

So far I accomplished two things in C:

a) Display a colored pixel on a specified screen location;

b) Record the location of a screen where a user has touched it.

To me it seems that using (a) and (b) I can in theory build an arbitrary complex app, using the following code:

```
struct AppState {
    // My implementation of the state representing everything that's happening in the app.
} app_state;

struct TouchEvent {
    int x, y;
};

// Sets TouchEvent.x to -1 if a user hasn't touched a screen lately
struct TouchEvent GetTouchEvent();

// Draws pixels on a screen depending on what state the app is
void DrawPixels(struct AppState* app_state);

void UpdateAppState(struct AppState* app_state, struct TouchEvent touch_event);

void main() {
    while (true) {
        struct TouchEvent touch_event = GetTouchEvent();
        UpdateAppState(&app_state, touch_event);    
        DrawPixels(&app_state);
        sleep(SOME_TIME);
    }
}
```

The `DrawPixels` method can be clever to not re-render the whole screen if the `app_state` indicates the screen hasn't changed. If I need a background thread to do some stuff invisible to the user, I can also add that too.

My question is: does every Android app work like this on a machine level code? Or does this design have some important gap, if yes, what kind of gap?

Comment: For now not, but it can be a further optimization to explore.

Comment: @jxh, doesn't the entire screen on a smartphone get refreshed at a certain frequency?

Answer (score 1):

For rendering, there is both fps and screen frequency. The fps is the speed at which an app is able to produce a full new image to draw. The frequency of the screen is electrical. It refers to the speed at which a full screen scan can be done. For example, 60hz = 60 potential screen refresh per second.

If there is no input or reason to change the image rendered on the screen, then Android doesn't do it.

All apps on any OS work like you said. There is an infinite loop that queries a list of inputs and dispatches them to do something based on the input type and its position. Machine code doesn't do that though. This is high level logic made possible by the programming language you are using whatever it may be.

Comment: a) Is the way a screen scan done that you have a buffer in memory allocated, and some dedicated hardware reads the buffer (at the frequency rate) and emits light on a screen based on that?

Comment: b) If yes to (a), can C code write directly into that buffer? For example, suppose I need to update only a single pixel. I update one integer of that buffer. Can this be accomplished on a C software level?

Comment: c) If yes to (a), does the hardware always re-render a full buffer, or does it instruct only a particular LED (e.g. the one for which the value in the buffer has changed) to emit a different light?

Comment: For a, it can work like that but most GPUs today have on chip memory. They probably all support framebuffer modes but, if you want to use its full speed, you'd want the image data in the GPU memory and use 3D commands to instruct it to change that image in a certain way (avoid transferring data from RAM as it is costly).

Comment: For b, no you can't. You need a syscall implemented by the OS. The OS reads the buffer from user mode and writes it on the framebuffer.

Comment: For c, the hardware renders a whole buffer. HDMI doesn't have an address bus. It has only a few pins. Probably one pin to start a scan and 3 pins for the colors and you do a full scan of the screen each time (potentially 60 times per second).